# generate a report according to the value in table A columns

Tags: db2

suppose I have to generate a report with few columns like

report:

| ID | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | zee | Y |
| 11 | sew | N |

table A

| ID | name | oldvalue | newvalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | sew | Y | N |
| 12 | zee | N | Y |
| 13 | dee | N | N |
| 14 | xee | Y | Y |
| 15 | pew | N | N |

I only want value changed from **y to n** or vice versa how can I code this using DB2.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Run a SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id, name, newvalue as value
From tablea
where (oldvalue, newvalue) in
(values ('Y', 'N'), ('N', 'Y'))
```